# How to replace a char from char array in C Program

Tags: c, arrays, shell, execvp

I am developing a shell code in C. Currently, my task is to redirect stdin to stdout with different commands, for instance cat < hello.c -ne > test.txt

I am able to do it, but my code tries to open "<" and ">" file as well, so for that I tried to assign 0 value which doesn't give me any error but ignores -ne.

Here is my code,

```
int in, out;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if(strcmp( argv[i],"<")==0) {

        in = open(argv[i+1], O_RDONLY);
        if (!in)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            //   argv[i]=0;
            // array[i+1]=0;
    }
    else if(strcmp( argv[i],">")==0) {
        out = open(argv[i+1], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
        if (!out)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            //    argv[i]=0;
            // array[i+1]=0;
    }
}
dup2(in, 0);
dup2(out, 1);
// close unused file descriptors

close(in);
close(out);
char *bname;
char *path2 = strdup(*argv);
bname = basename(path2);        
//printf("%d",argc);            

/*the command will be executed using execvp*/                           
execvp(bname, argv);
```

argv array would be like

```
argv[0]="cat"
argv[1]="<"
argv[2]="hello.c"
argv[3]="-ne"
argv[4]=">"
argv[5]="test.txt"
```

Basically, I want to open multiple files in between "<" and ">" and then redirect to the given file after ">".

The current Output-

```
$ ./shell
Enter Shell Command -- cat < hello.c -ne > te1.txt


$ cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: te1.txt: input file is output file
```

Comment: The serious approach would be to sanity check the whole list of command line arguments before you start to open any files. When dealing with that  person we call user, they can type "cat la la la" for all we know.

Comment: Can you please give me a code example.

Comment: One problem I see is that when you seen "<" "hello.c" you need to increment i because you have processed two arguments in that loop iteration.

Comment: You need to shift the remaining arguments two places to the left to erase the `< filename`.

Comment: As Lundin said, you should check your whole command is correct (Does it have multiple redirections? Does it have `;` `&` `|` ... ? Is the syntax OK?), then maybe build a list of commands storing redirections settings. For example how would you process `cat < test.c > test.txt | cat | cat < foo`?

Comment: @Eregrith I have used strtok_r() to do that, and am splitting by ';'. so that would not be the case.

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson I tried to add a value in I on each condition at the end, but the result is still the same.

Comment: @interjay that does make sense, let me try it.

Comment: @RaviVyas Ok. What about `cat < test.c > test.txt | cat | cat < foo` ? You need to check those incorrect multiple redicrections or handle it somehow

Comment: @Eregrith yeah correct !

Comment: @Eregrith can you give me any code example ? I am trying but nothing is working at the moment.

Comment: @RaviVyas I'm afraid I can't, such an example would require quite a bit of code. And in order to understand it you should do it yourself too.